# Error OwnCloud ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, apache, mariadb

Acabo de instalar mi servidor de ownCloud en Ubuntu 20.04 y tengo problemas a la hora de acceder a través del navegador, en el mismo equipo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la base de datos, he usado los dos usuarios que tengo creados y no me ha funcionado. También he probado con `localhost`, con y sin puerto, pero nada, no funciona.

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias.